# How a Mevo's camera hotspot works on Android?

Tags: android, facebook, video-streaming, android-wifi

Android doesn't support simultaneously work of Wi-Fi and mobile internet except creating hotspot on android device. But the Mevo camera can stream on Facebook by two ways: connecting to the access point of the phone and using the mobile Internet and the second way - when the Mevo acts, as the master and the phone connects to the wifi of the camera (https://help.getmevo.com/hc/en-us/articles/115008282988-Connecting-Android-Devices-to-Mevo-Hotspot). The Internet is not available, except for streaming to Facebook (plus other services that Mevo supports). Does anyone have the ideas how the Mevo camera can make streaming to Facebook with Mevo's Hotspot?

Comment: Apparently, Mevo uses [Wi-Fi Direct™](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifip2p.html). From Android 8.0 (API level 26) and higher, an app can [discover and connect](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/wifi-aware.html) such Wi-Fi service automatically.

Comment: @AlexCohn, thank you for your comment, but let me clarify my issue. An application needs to connect through WiFi to other device, to get video stream from one and then to make live stream to Facebook, that is, ideally I would want to have WiFi and cellular connection simultaneously, but without creating hotspot on android device.

Comment: This is exactly what Wi-Fi Direct™ is about. tTe Android device connects to Mevo's service.